# How to use DECLARE statement in plpgsql function correctly. ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have created a function that should return a set of attributes from different tables based on some parameters.

In order to obtain the result, I have created a TYPE and applied multiple INNER JOIN statements

When I call the function I receive the following

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

Here is my code:

SET search_path to olympic;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (register_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor_name tb_sponsor.name%type)
RETURNS SETOF sponsor_data AS $$
DECLARE 
 data_sponsor sponsor_data;
 email  olympic.email_type;
 sponsor_name tb_finance.sponsor_name%type;
 athlete_name tb_athlete.name%type;
 discilpine_name tb_discipline.name%type;
 round_number  tb_register.round_number%type;
 mark tb_register.register_measure%type;
 register_position tb_register.register_position%type;
 register_date  tb_register.register_ts%type;
 BEGIN 
      SELECT 
           tb_finance.sponsor_name,
           tb_sponsor.email email_type,
           tb_athlete.name AS athlete_name,
           tb_discipline.name AS discipline_name,
           tb_register.round_number,
           tb_register.register_measure,
           tb_register.register_position,
           tb_register.register_ts
      INTO  data_sponsor
      FROM  olympic.tb_sponsor
           
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance

           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)

      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete

           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id

      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register

           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id

      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline

           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id

      ORDER BY  tb_register.register_ts;
      
      RETURN NEXT data_sponsor;
 END;
 $$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 

 SELECT * FROM fn_get_info_by_sponsor('2021-06-02 00:00:00','Reebok')
```

I guess I have made a mistake in the DECLARE statement, but I am not sure how to solve this. Can anyone help?

(I have used multiple tables this is why I am not adding the CREATE TABLE statements here to simplify)

Thank you(:

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with `MySQL` so I removed the tag 2) The function is broken in multiple ways, I would suggest some time spent here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). In particular [Select into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) and [Return query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY.

Comment: Thenk you @AdrianKlaver I have updated by question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple **sql function** instead of plpgsql function here.
Just check the list of fields provided by the query and which must conform the `sponsor_data` type in the rigth fields order.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (register_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor_name tb_sponsor.name%type)
RETURNS sponsor_data LANGUAGE sql AS $$
      SELECT row(
                 tb_sponsor.email,
                 tb_finance.sponsor_name,
                 tb_athlete.name AS athlete_name,
                 tb_discipline.name AS discipline_name,
                 tb_register.round_number,
                 tb_register.register_measure, -- = mark of type CHARACTER(12) ?
                 tb_register.register_position,
                 tb_register.register_ts -- = register_date of type date ?
                ) :: sponsor_data 
      FROM  olympic.tb_sponsor
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance
           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete
           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register
           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline
           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id
      ORDER BY  tb_register.register_ts ;
$$ 

 SELECT * FROM fn_get_info_by_sponsor('2021-06-02 00:00:00','Reebok')
```

Or you can create a **PL/pgSQL function** to do the same :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (register_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor_name tb_sponsor.name%type)
RETURNS sponsor_data LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
      sp_data sponsor_data ;
BEGIN
      SELECT row(
                 tb_sponsor.email,
                 tb_finance.sponsor_name,
                 tb_athlete.name AS athlete_name,
                 tb_discipline.name AS discipline_name,
                 tb_register.round_number,
                 tb_register.register_measure, -- = mark of type CHARACTER(12) ?
                 tb_register.register_position,
                 tb_register.register_ts -- = register_date of type date ?
                ) :: sponsor_data
       INTO sp_data
       FROM olympic.tb_sponsor
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance
           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete
           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register
           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline
           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id
      ORDER BY  tb_register.register_ts ;

      RETURN sp_data ;
END ;  
$$ 

 SELECT * FROM fn_get_info_by_sponsor('2021-06-02 00:00:00','Reebok')
```

Comment: Thank you @Eduard that is really helpful. But I would like to understand the difference between the slq and plpgsql and be able to use both. I have updated my question.

Comment: SQL is the language for interacting with any kind of Relational Database Management System like PostGreSQL, mySQL, Oracle... You can either create [query language (SQL) functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/xfunc-sql.html) or [procedural language like PL/pgSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/xfunc-pl.html). PL/pgSQL can do more than SQL see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql.html).

Comment: Answer updated with the equivalent PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: @Eduard thank you for all the help. The issue is solved. Now I just need to dive into the manual you have recommended. Thank you (:

Comment: @KlauRau - SQL functions are +/- macros in PostgreSQL ecosystems - you can write "parametrized views" - the functionality is same like views, but allows parametrization. PL/pgSQL functions allows to use full functionality of stored procedures - procedural language + embedded SQL. The advantages of SQL functions is inlining. PL/pgSQL functions can use full functionality, but for the planner it is black box. SQL functions can be inlined to outer query and optimized together. This is not possible for PL/pgSQL functions.